# How can I access my email with python imaplib or otherwise?

Tags: python, email, imap

My email account requires 4 pieces of information in order to connect to it:

1. Email address
2. Incoming mail server
3. Password
4. Username to the server (not the same as email)

Using imaplib I'm able to do the following:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('server_url', 993)
mail.login(email_address, password)
```

This uses the first three on the list but I couldn't find an argument or a method that would also allow me to specify the username to the server (not same as email). Where can I input that username to be able to connect?

[Here is how I set it up in settings on mac, I need to do the equivalent in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t77LV.png)

Thank you

Comment: Login uses the username.  You use the email address if you're building an new email to send, it's usually not used for logging in.

Comment: in some servers email (`username@server.com`) is used as login. In other servers  `username` from `username@server.com` is used as login.

Comment: I don't know where you need username to the server. Normally it needs only `login(username, password)` to access mails. If you get error then you should show it in question because at this moment it can be [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I didn't realise that `username` actually referred to the server username rather than email. Thank you @Max for pointing this out. That fixed the problem.